# Getting "Maximum execution time ... exceeded" when sending some PDFs in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form to upload an PDF to send on email attachment using PHPMailer class.

I have my form that asks for a title and a pdf to upload:

If user doesn't fill in my fields he will get a message saying to fill all fields, else it will upload my file to my newsletter folder.

And then I using my function `sendEmail` to send my email with my attachments, but it's not working with PDFs of large size.

I tested width PDFs of 259kb and it works fine, but with PDFs of 489kb (only more 200kb) don't work,  I get always the same error:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in class.smtp.php

My PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['send_form']))
{

    $f['subject'] = $_POST['subject'];

    if(in_array('',$f) || empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']) )
    {
        echo '<span>Please Fill all fields!</span>';
    }
    else
    {

    if(!empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $folder     = '../newsletter/'; 
        $year   = date('Y');
        $month  = date('m');

    if(!file_exists($folder.$year)){
        mkdir($folder.$year,0755);
    }

    if(!file_exists($folder.$year.'/'.$month)){
        mkdir($folder.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
    }

    $pdf= $_FILES['pdf'];
    $ext = substr($pdf['name'],-3); 
    $f['pdf'] = $f['subject'].".".$ext;
    $attachment = $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$f['pdf'];
    move_uploaded_file($pdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$f['pdf']);
   }
   }
}
```

Then I send email:

```
sendMail($f['subject'],$msg,MAILUSER,'Name of sender','testEmail03@hotmail.com', 'emailReceptor03@hotmail.com');
```

My function `sendEmail`:

```
function sendMail($subject,$message,$emissor,$emissorName,$receptor,$receptorName, $attachment, $reply = NULL, $replyName = NULL){

    require_once('mail/class.phpmailer.php'); 

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
    $mail->Host = MAILHOST; 
    $mail->Port = MAILPORT; 
    $mail->Username = MAILUSER;
    $mail->Password = MAILPASS;    
    $mail->From = utf8_decode($emissor); 
    $mail->FromName = utf8_decode($emissorName); 
    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($subject); 
    $mail->Body = utf8_decode($message);
    $mail->AddAddress(utf8_decode($receptor),utf8_decode($receptorName)); 
    $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);

    if($reply != NULL){
    $mail->AddReplyTo(utf8_decode($reply),utf8_decode($replyNome)); 
    }

    if($mail->Send()){
    return true;
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

If I change in my php.ini max_execution_time=30 to max_execution_time=60, I dont get errors but I dont receive any email!

Comment: Are the PDF files large? Larger than the images ? One solution would be to simply increase the max_execution_time in your php.ini file.

Comment: What size are we talking about (PDF) ? Even if you're able to bypass php limitation of time execution, you might hit email service max size attachment limit (~15-20 MB on most services). Consider compressing the files before sending in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Bonatoc and vlzvl. I think problem is really about pdf size, because now I try with a pdf with 259kb and it works. But with 486kb pdf its not working. Do you know how I can send pdf in attachment with at least 2mb??

Comment: this is simply  because mail->send() cannot complete in max_execution_time due to file size, you either need better upload speeds or to increase max_execution_time

Comment: Thanks for your answer Quad, Im not much familiar with php.ini configs. I acess it and I have like this: max_execution_time=30, There is some correct value to this?

Comment: Because I change to max_execution_time=60, and now I dont get errors but I dont receive any email!

Comment: Maybe the 400Kb+ PDF is getting stuck for other reasons, e.g. it is being regarded as spam. Try a different email address, with a different provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer halfer. It is working when I send email for a gmail user, but for hotmail dont works, I checked span folder and its empty! Do you have any suggestion how put this work for other emails providers?

Comment: Add the "from" email to the recipient's address book - usually that improves the tolerance of the filter. ("You must know this guy you have his email address")